# How to wait until if statement is done? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await

I try to return an array of cards. The list with card is empty at the moment when I return the list. But that's only because the if statement is not finished. Does someone know how I can wait until the if statement is done?

```
fun getAllCards(): MutableList<Card> {
    val cards = mutableListOf<Card>()

    fireStore.collection("cards")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener {
                task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                for (document in task.result) {
                    cards.add(Card((document.data["value"]).toString().toFloat()))
                }

            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.exception)

            }

        }
   return cards
}
```

Comment: `But that's only because the if statement is not finished.` No that is because the OnCompleteListener is not triggered yet. Your function returns before the get has been executed. Wrong design. Your function cannot return the list. Handle the list if task succcessfull. Well you do it there already..

Comment: You cannot directly return an object from a callback directly to the caller. From what I know you can either use the callback pattern or use `suspend fun` + `suspendCoroutine` approach.